# How to find the probability that...

Tags: probability

I'm in a high school statistics course and for the end of the semester, we have a small project. Summing things up, the question I'm trying to do for my project is what is the probability an NBA player can score more than 70 points.

How would I go on about this? Do I take the average of career-high of NBA players and then use the Z-Table? We didn't really do examples like this in class and they were pretty simple compared to this since you are already given the needed numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Get data on as many NBA players as possible.  Then plot a histogram.  Then draw a line at $70$ points.  Compute the probability to the right (higher) than it.  Done!

Comment: Assuming the performance of NBA players form a normal distribution, your approach would also work. You just need to gather data, properly compute z-scores. Quick google search returned this example: https://www.sophia.org/tutorials/using-z-scores-to-find-a-probability-2 . It is not great but fits your purposes.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Thanks. Just one question. Does it make a difference if I take multiple career highs of a single player in my data or no? For example, should I just collect a single-game high of every player. Lebron's career-high is 61, but he has multiple 50 point games. Should I only use the 61 in my data or is it cool to take let's say like the average of his 10 highest scoring games. Is one way more correct than the other in the real world?

Comment: Just to say:  nobody scores $≥70$ in an NBA game, not any more and not in the past unless that player was named Wilt Chamberlain.  Ok, Kobe did it, and David Robinson (once each, if memory serves).  And the old Wilt numbers are irrelevant (since the game was quite different then).  To get a meaningful answer I'd say you are going to need to model the distribution of points.

Comment: Just looked it up...The Robinson result is a bit fishy.  Last game of the season against the non-contending Clippers.  Even then, the Spurs had to foul intentionally a whole lot of times (despite having a $≥20$ point lead) in order to get the ball back to Robinson so he could boost his score.  I don't think the raw data is your friend here.

Comment: Here is some [data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_National_Basketball_Association_single-game_scoring_leaders) on the most points NBA players have scored in a game.

Comment: @JosephBailey I would treat each game of each player separately. Like if I were looking at LeBron's 10 games, I would say LeBron1, LeBron2, ..., LeBron10. However, at that point it is a philosophical question. As long as you explain your data gathering and data processing steps clearly, which should show that you are not biasing your data to obtain the result you want, it should be okay. To me, this seems like a practice to teach you data science. So show your skills, explain your methodology well, clearly state your assumptions and you are golden!